# Asus ROG Phone II vs OnePlus 7T vs iPhone XR

Tags: gaming, smartphones

I want to buy a new phone for Gaming purposes.
Below are my requirements.

```
1. Performance is the topmost priority
2. Camara performance can be neglected
3. Long battery backup
4. Headphone-jack is preferable
5. Durability should be also be taken into consideration
6. Excellent screen quality
```

And my budget is 40-42k, So which of the phones mentioned in the title should I buy?

**Note:-** I won't say I am a hardcore gamer but definitely a passionate one.

Comment: The 7T (non-pro) definitely fails in the screen department - mine had some horribly uneven gray levels at lower brightness. The XR is *really* weak in comparison to the other two.
Perhaps the "Nubia Red Magic 3S" might be an option too? I have no idea how much it costs in your market though.

Comment: Good suggestion though!! It would cost around 43k INR for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just going off of Geekbench data for these devices (Higher is better):

ASUS ROG Phone 2:
Single Core: 722
Multi Core: 2467
CPU Clock: 1.8GHz (approx)
Core Count: 8

OnePlus 7T: 
Single Core: 760
Multi Core: 2695
CPU Clock: 1.8 GHz (approx)
Core Count: 8

iPhone XR:
Single Core: 1108
Multi Core: 2573
CPU Clock: 2.5 GHz (Approx)
Core Count: 6

The ASUS ROG Phone 2 and OnePlus 7T are very similar due to the phone using the same chipset for CPU.

If I was making this decision, I’d get the iPhone Xr. iPhones just work, where Android has too many areas (in my opinion) to break and cause issues for the user. I am also an Apple fan boy though. I have an iPhone XR, and it takes everything I throw at it. I left it in a snow bank for 30 minutes and it still works no issues.

Comment: I was also thinking about iPhone XR, but one thing is keeping me away from buying iPhone is it doesn't have a headphone jack. What do you say?

Comment: I’d say to do one of these things. Buy the Lightning jack to 3.5 adapter for 10$ in the USA since one doesn’t come with it (ever wonder how  Apple is worth 1 Trillion dollars), use the lightning cable earpods that come with the phone, or buy some wireless earbuds or headphones

Comment: you are right, 10$ in USA won't be a big deal, but in my country India it is kinda a big deal to spend extra 1k INR for me. Anyway thanks for your help, (Accepted)

Comment: just came to know that iPhone XR doesn't even have an FHD screen. A big no

Comment: Yes, the iPhone XR doesn't have an FHD screen, but the screen quality is awesome compared to some similar phones in the market. I would personally still buy the iPhone XR